# How to automatically resize controls based on the language associated .resx info?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I got some legacy .net code and modified the application so it can be multilanguage.

I've set the Form's Localizable propriety to True and created a Language and made the necessary modifications with the designer for each language.

I can easily update all the control's text to the correct language, but I can't figure out how to redraw the main Window with all its tablelayouts.

Basically, for each language, in the associated .resx, at "Others", I have the sizes I want it to be redrawn/refreshed to:

`$this.ClientSize    System.Drawing.Size 815, 700`

```
cmdCloseForm.Location   System.Drawing.Point    781, 6

cmdMinimize.Location    System.Drawing.Point    757, 6

pictureBoxBanner.Size   System.Drawing.Size 807, 90

tableLayoutPanel1.Size  System.Drawing.Size 204, 530

tableLayoutPanel2.Size  System.Drawing.Size 807, 90

tableLayoutPanel4.Location  System.Drawing.Point    212, 125

tableLayoutPanelAbout.Location  System.Drawing.Point    212, 125
[...]
```

How can I resize all of these, because there must be a way to automatically do it(the designer is capable of resizing everything, if the language is changed, for example..), given the fact that they are stored in the resx.. I've tried refreshing the main Form, freezing it and refreshing it.. to no avail. How can I make the program aware of the fact that, if the language is changed, to automatically resize/move all the controls in the language .resx to the sizes specified there?

Answer (score 0):

It could be difficult to retrofit to a legacy app, but Microsoft recommend using `TableLayout`, `AutoSize` and `Anchor` in [Walkthrough: Creating a Layout That Adjusts Proportion for Localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k9fa71y.aspx)